# Monotonicity of $ f'$

Tags: real-analysis, monotone-functions

Let $f(x)=\sin x-x+\frac {x^3}{6}$ and  $g(x)=\cos x-1+\frac {x^2}{2}$ for $x\in \Bbb R$.Then How to prove that $f(x)\ge 0$ for all $x\ge 0$?

From given function it is clear that $f'=g$ and $g'(x)=x-\sin x$ hence $g'(x)\ge0$, hence $g$ is increasing function and hence $f'$. But my question is, if $f' $ is increasing function how to prove that $f(x)\ge 0$ for all $x\ge 0$?

Comment: To show that $f(x)\ge 0$ for all $x\ge 0$, it is sufficient to show that $f(0)=0$ and $f'(t)\ge 0$ (i.e. $\color{blue}{g(t)\ge 0}$) for all $t \ge 0$. Can you show this?

Answer (score 1):

Because now by the definition of the increasing function we obtain:  $$f(x)\geq f(0)=0.$$

Comment: Yes understood.